# UBound Array vb6 Conversion to C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vb6, vb6-migration

I have the following code in VB6:

```
Dim frpdReport() As REPORTDEF

For iCounter = 0 To UBound(frpdReport)

    With frpdReport(iCounter)
        If .iReportID = iReportID Then
            fGetReportFile = .tReportFile
        End If
    End With
Next iCounter
```

And I converted to this C# code:

```
REPORTDEF[] frpdReport = new REPORTDEF[6];
 for (iCounter = 0; iCounter < Convert.ToInt32(frpdReport[6]); iCounter++)
    {
        if (frpdReport[iCounter].iReportID == iReportID)
        {
            fGetReportFile_return = frpdReport[iCounter].tReportFile;
        }

    }
    return fGetReportFile_return;
```

When debugging I get the following error in the for Statement - "Index was outside the bounds of the array." And I cannot figure out why since the index of the array is 6.

Any help please?

Comment: Note that those code samples don;t even start the same, and there is something missing from the VB6 sample after the `Dim` as that will fail with an unitialised array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use the .length property?

```
 for (iCounter = 0; iCounter < frpdReport.Length; iCounter++)
```

or if you don't need the counter value, a for each

```
foreach (REPORTDEF frpReportItem in frpdReport)
```

Or if you are looking for a specific item, use LINQ

```
REPORTDEF fGetReportFile_return = frpdReport.Where( fR => fR.iReportID == iReportID).Single();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the length of an array using `arrayName.Length`.

```
for (iCounter = 0; iCounter < frpdReport.Length; iCounter++) 
{ 
    if (frpdReport[iCounter].iReportID == iReportID) 
    { 
        fGetReportFile_return = frpdReport[iCounter].tReportFile; 
    } 
} 
return fGetReportFile_return;
```

Or the simple `foreach` construct:

```
foreach (REPORTDEF frpdReportItem in frpdReport) 
{ 
    if (frpdReportItem.iReportID == iReportID) 
    { 
        fGetReportFile_return = frpdReportItem.tReportFile; 
    } 
} 
return fGetReportFile_return;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
for (iCounter = 0; iCounter < Convert.ToInt32(frpdReport[6]); iCounter++)
```

It should be:

```
for (iCounter = 0; iCounter < 6; iCounter++)
```

`frpdReport` was defined as a six-element array; in C#, arrays are zero-based, so `frpdReport[6]` will generate an error, since there are only elements 0 through 5.

Comment: Thats right. I was working wiht 1based vb6 and forgot that c# was 0based. Thanks for point that out to me.

Answer (score 0):

`REPORTDEF[6]` defines 6 elements, from 0 to 5.

`Convert.ToInt32(frpdReport[6])` does not seem to make sense at all. You are converting a structure to a number.

Comment: Thats right. I was working wiht 1based vb6 and forgot that c# was 0based. Thanks for point that out to me.